# Code to sample from & integrate light of a cluster?

Tags: astrophysics, software, stellar-population

Are there any publicly available codes to sample from an initial mass function (common ones... Kroupa, Chabrier, Salpeter) to construct a cluster, then use stellar models to generate an integrated spectrum?  I imagine such codes must be quite common, as they're relatively easy to write, but require access to stellar model databases or very simple stellar models.

Comment: SLUG (https://sites.google.com/site/runslug) does a lot of what I want, but only incorporated into full-scale Galaxy simulation.  It's probably possibly to make it generate just one cluster.

Comment: The astrophysics source code library (http://asterisk.apod.com/viewforum.php?f=35) is another place to look. I did a quick search for "initial mass function", and SLUG came up, but nothing that seemed much more specifically suited to your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The one population synthesis code I've used is GALAXEV, which can be found [here](http://www2.iap.fr/users/charlot/bc2003/). It allows you to choose either the Chabrier or Salpeter IMF, as well as select a star formation history from a few simple models, and it outputs the integrated spectrum. The stellar models and evolutionary tracks are all included in the code and supporting files.

I will caution, however, that this code, despite its popularity, is written in near-defunct Fortran. It took me several days to get it working, between figuring out its ancient I/O format, running preliminary scripts to convert between ASCII and binary files (yes the authors believe reading in a few kilobytes of ASCII data somehow takes a significant amount of time), and finding a compiler from the post-vacuum tube era that actually accepted the source. Yet one more example of astronomy being several decades behind when it comes to computers...

Comment: Well, sounds like a great candidate to get wrapped in python... astronomy's not ALL behind, but there are plenty of astronomers who are.